Cannot install any package with vcpkg on my Visual Studio 2022 C++ project
I have searched similar questions on StackOverflow but I couldn't quite find a case close to mine, so I am finally writing my own question after battling with this over tens of hours.
I am trying to install a basic C++ library such as Eigen3, with the command as simple as .\vcpkg install eigen3. However, it is throwing me a directory finding error, which it seems very simple and yet I cannot find a solution to.
error: 컴파일러 정보를 감지하는 동안:
"C:\agbami_data\c++_project\autotrans_cpp_12\vcpkg\buildtrees\detect_compiler\stdout-x64-windows.log"의 로그 파일 콘텐츠는 다음과 같습니다.
CMake Error at C:/agbami_data/c++_project/autotrans_cpp_12/vcpkg/scripts/ports.cmake:139 (message):
  Cannot find port:

    Directory does not exist: C;/agbami_data/c++_project/autotrans_cpp_12/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler


error: vcpkg가 활성 컴파일러 정보를 감지할 수 없습니다. CMake 실패 출력은 위를 참조하세요.

You see, there is clearly a typo C;/agbami_data/..., which I strongly believe is the cause of this problem, but I don't know where to tell my computer that it is actually : instead of ;. A problem that appears to be a piece of cake, but turns out it is not(at least for me).
For additional information about my environment please refer to the following:

Visual Studio 2022
C++ 17 compiler
CMake ver 3.30.0

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like below. And I only have another source file that only performs printing "Hello CMake.", which is a very basic setting that you create at first.
# CMakeList.txt: autotrans_cpp_12에 대한 CMake 프로젝트, 여기에 소스를 포함하고
# 프로젝트 특정 논리를 정의합니다.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# 지원되는 경우 MSVC 컴파일러에 대해 핫 다시 로드 사용하도록 설정합니다.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("autotrans_cpp_12")

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)


# 이 프로젝트의 실행 파일에 소스를 추가합니다.
add_executable (autotrans_cpp_12 "autotrans_main.cpp" "autotrans_main.h")

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET autotrans_cpp_12 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: 필요한 경우 테스트를 추가하고 대상을 설치합니다.


It might have been affected by my previous configurations on previous projects. But I am freshly starting entirely a new project just to present this issue, that it persists even if I create another project, as simply as possible.
If anyone can lend me a hand by providing useful tips, I would much appreciate and give you votes and thumbs up.
Thanks.

Did you do a search for the string "C;/agbami_data" in any of your project files? Perhaps finding and replacing the string (after a backup!) could solve the problem? Maybe it is in the PATH variable of the environment?

Does this answer your question? Chances are your CMake binary is from MSYS2, which is a little too overzealous in converting colons to semicolons (because of Windows path limitations). Install the native Windows binary from here, and make sure your PATH is set such that the Windows CMake directory has higher priority, as detailed in that answer.
